# I need help with my Minecraft dog

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I get a little to attached to virtual pets (don't ask me why), especially Minecraft because I like to self- role play as I play Minecraft. Anyway, I especially like to feed them,even if I'm not trying to breed or raise their health. I find I feel loved if I get the heart particle. I've been trying to feed my dog steak (and yes, it's cooked), but he won't eat unless his health is down, and I hate to punch him just to make him eat. And when he does eat, I get no particle effect. I've tried both in creative and survival, and both have this problem. Is this just a bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Someone please answer me! Someone just randomly hit the down arrow without even telling me why!

Comment: Turn on particles in Game menu -> Settings -> Video settings -> Particles: All/Reduced/Minimal maybe?

Comment: NOW I REMEMBER!!!!! Thank you, Rudolf L. Jenlinek! I was playing on an amplified world setting for the first time, so to reduce lag, I turned of a lot of aesthetics settings. Including particles. Thank you!

Comment: How do I mark this as answered?

Comment: @MinecraftAttached You don't... Well, not until someone submits a formal answer below.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you turned off particle effects. You can turn them back on in the graphical settings (ESC/main menu -> settings -> video settings). You have to set the particle setting either to "all" or to "reduced" to see heart particles.

Answer (score 1):

One reason that there might not be the particle effects is that you're feeding them soon after being fed earlier. The time is 5 minutes. Wait 5 minutes, and you can probably get the particles again once you attempt to feed them again.

Quote from the Minecraft wiki:

> They will not be able to enter love mode again for 5 minutes, and they may only breed once per item given.

Link to the wiki page: [Mincraft Wiki: Breeding](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Breeding)